# Calculated properties do not throw exceptions in Powershell. What are the workaround possibilities?

Tags: powershell, exception

Apparently there is a [by design quirk](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/782806/calculated-properties-do-not-throw-exceptions) in Powershell that prevents exceptions that are thrown inside a [Calculated Property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) Expression from bubbling up. All that happens is the value of the Calculated Property ends up being null.

```
function Get-KBValue() {
    # Some Logic here that can throw an exception
}

....

Get-ChildItem C:\Test | 
    Select-Object Name, CreationTime,  @{Name="Kbytes"; Expression={ Get-KBValue }}
```

If the `Get-KBValue` function throws an exception then the value of the `Kbytes` property is set to `$null` and the script continues.

#### Possible workarounds:

- Use `try/catch{break}` within the Expression (Suggested by @C.B.)
- Validate afterwards. Although this might be complicated by the fact that `$null` could be valid in some cases.
- Use a custom object instead of a calculated property. But this is not as nice.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a try/cacth in expression can help you?

```
10..0 | SELECT @{n="Value";e={ try { 10/$_ } catch { "error: $_" }}}
```

Comment: @x0n What a grateful comment! More than a thousand upvotes! Thank you Sir Grehan.. ;)

Comment: Does `"error: $_"` actually halt execution like an exception would?

Comment: @AndyMcCluggage Nope! You need to add a break: `catch { "error: $_"; break }`